# login with google into iphone sdk with IOS 5 or Later

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

I want to login with google for authentication and share resources using my iphone application. Is there any API or tutorial available for integrating Google into iPhone Application for the latest IOS.

Comment: Are you talking about GTM OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

for login to google you have provide "username","password" and google server name that is "talk.google.com"

see above link for xmppchat application.in APPDelegate.m delegate methods are there in that one method is didAuthenticate method

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{


}
```

Above method verifies username and password is correct or not. if username and password is correct then it show you online to your friends.

Answer (score 0):

The Objective-C library for Google APIs is at

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Comment: I think The Objective C code is for Mac OS x, I need for iPhone SDK(IOS).